# How to add JsonArrayObject in JsonArray

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, json.net, ocelot

Here I am trying to implement `Ocelot` for API Gateway for my multiple micro services. I have Seven Micro services which have lots of API almost 550 APIs. While preparing ocelot.json it is a huge file which seems unmaintainable. For which I want to have different json array objects for each services. Those array objects to be inserted to in routes array of ocelot.json. I have a sample ocelot.json like this:

```
{
   "Routes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/ObjectHeads/GetObjectHeadFromBudget?{everything}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 59035
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/ObjectHeads/GetObjectHeadFromBudget?{everything}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get" ]
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/ObjectHeads/GetObjectHeadByDepartmentWise?{everything}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 44358
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/ObjectHeads/GetObjectHeadByDepartmentWise?{everything}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get" ]
    }
   ],
   "GlobalConfiguration": {
   "BaseUrl": "https://localhost:7000"
   }
}
```

It is working absolutely fine I am able to perform `get`, `pos`t from different `micro services`. Now my concern is there a way to add json array objects in routes array in the ocelot.json? I am bit new to the json as I never worked on it. Is there a way out for managing such stuff. I am sure that somebody may have gone through such situation, there may be a solution. My program.cs looks simple like this.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Configuration
    .AddJsonFile("ocelot.json")
    .AddJsonFile($"ocelot.{builder.Environment.EnvironmentName}.json");

 builder.Services.AddOcelot()
    .AddDelegatingHandler<RequestLogger>()
    .AddCacheManager(settings => settings.WithDictionaryHandle())
    .AddCustomLoadBalancer((serviceProvider, downstreamRoute, serviceDiscoveryProvider) =>
    {
        return new CustomLoadBalancer(serviceDiscoveryProvider.Get);
    });

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseOcelot();

app.Run();
```

Any solutions and suggestions are highly appreciated please.

Comment: Manipulating json from code is not a problem. But how are you planning to generate the entries for this json? Are you planning to iterate all the services and use their swagger.json to generate ocelot.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can download json directly , not using config

```
    var path = @"C:\...";
    // or maybe you can try this
    var path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

    var filePath = Path.Combine(path, "ocelot.json");
    var json = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

    var jObj = JObject.Parse(json);

    var newRoute = new
    {
        DownstreamPathTemplate = "/api/ObjectHeads/GetObjectHeadByDepartmentWise?{everything}",
        DownstreamScheme = "https",
        DownstreamHostAndPorts = new[] {
        new {
         Host= "localhost",
          Port= 44358
        }
      },
        UpstreamPathTemplate = "/ObjectHeads/GetObjectHeadByDepartmentWise?{everything}",
        UpstreamHttpMethod = new string[] { "Get" }
    };
    
     ((JArray)jObj["Routes"]).Add(JObject.FromObject(newRoute));
     
      File.WriteAllText(filePath,jObj.ToString());
```

Answer (score -1):

For json text starts with `{}` is type of `JObject`. For starts with `[]` is type of `JArray`. And you need Nuget Package `Newtonsoft.Json` to convert `string` to `JObject` or `JArrary`

Below is a sample of read the first "route" and added it to the json file.

```
var directoryPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
string filePath = directoryPath + "\\ocelot.json"; //get file path

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath);       
string jsonString = sr.ReadToEnd();       //read the file to a string
sr.Close();

var jsonData = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString); // the string starts with '{}' so we convert to JObject
Console.WriteLine(jsonData);   //to check the jobject we get
var routes = (JArray)jsonData["Routes"];  //You can get element inside JObject by jsonData["a"]["b"] ,but the value of "Routes" starts with "[]" so convert it to JArray
var route1 = routes[0];       //You can get Arrary elements by index

StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filePath);
routes.Add(route1);          //add one more 1st route as example 
jsonData["Routes"] = routes;    //jsonData can be update by this syntax
sw.Write(jsonData);
sw.Close();
```